# What is the shortcut for 'change language mode' in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

When I press <kbd>cmd + K M</kbd> to access the "Change Language Mode" option in Visual Studio Code, it opens keymap extensions marketplace section. Is it a shortcut conflict or am I doing it wrong?

- Visual Studio Code Version: 1.20.1
- OS: MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Comment: In case you are in a Juypter Notebook, try selecting a cell (or press Esc if you are currently editing it) and pressing M for Markdown or Y for code.

Answer (score 58):

There is a space between <kbd>⌘K</kbd> and <kbd>M</kbd> in the [documentation for Mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_rich-languages-editing):

> Change Language Mode  ⌘K M workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode

So, on Mac:

- press <kbd>⌘</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> at the same time, release and then only press <kbd>M</kbd>.

On Windows the corresponding shortcut is similar:

- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>and<kbd>K</kbd> together, release and then press <kbd>M</kbd>

Comment: remember to release `⌘`/`CTRL` when you press `M`

Comment: Old topic, but this was driving me crazy.  Hopefully will help others.  The `CTRL-k` `M` shortcut does _not_ work unless you have "Editor Language" on display in your status bar.  Right click on your status bar to turn on this particular item.  **Update**: I just tried again and now `ctrl-k` `m` does not work for me again.  It just does nothing except display an `m` in my status bar.  However, using the "Editor Language" icon in the status bar as my means of switching is good enough for me.

Comment: @tanager {
  "key": "cmd+k m",
  "command": "workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode",
  "when": "!notebookEditorFocused"
} -> note when cause